# Fees/Taxes on Each Block Found

Tags: protocol, transaction-fees, altcoin, mining-software

Haven't found a clear answer to this, but I have heard that various coins charge a sort of "developer tax". I've looked through a bunch of various crypto's sourcecode, but I haven't found any hints as to how it's implemented, let alone in what portion of the code it would be in. 
Could someone reveal a little sunlight onto this behavior?

Comment: I have never heard anything of a developer tax.  Perhaps you are thinking of the block reward, which is the award given to the miner/pool who creates the block.

Comment: This is all really just something I've heard from a friend who I've felt had his coin around crypto implementation details,and I'm just playing with the idea more than anything. I wonder how something like that would be implemented anyway, because I could certainly see it be in the interests of devs to sort of "motivate" an ongoing relationship. I imagine this would have to be hard-coded into the block creation implementation, but I wonder if the SIGCHECKS would have to be altered to account for it.

Answer (score 1):

Some mining programs (designed for use with mining pools) will mine on behalf of the mining software developer for a short time, before switching to the actual user account.

I've only seen this once and I don't even remember which coin it was for, so I don't know how widespread it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about Devcoin.

http://www.devcoin.org/

Which sends out 90% of mined coins to the developers of the coin based on the csv files stored with the client.

http://www.devtome.com/doku.php?id=devcoin

> Receiver Files Client Procedure Receiver.h accesses a synchronized
>   list of receivers.
>
> For example, say the devcoin client requests the height 9000
>   receivers, the height step is 4000 and only the root receiver_0.csv
>   saved. Receiver.h will first look for the receiver_2.csv file. Since
>   it's not there it will step down and look for receiver_1.csv. Still
>   not there so it looks for and finds receiver_0.csv. It then downloads
>   receiver_1.csv by looking at the peers in receiver_0.csv and saves in
>   the data directory. It then downloads receiver_2.csv by looking at the
>   peers in receiver_1.csv and saves in the data directory. Once it has
>   receiver_2.csv, it parses it to get the list of receivers and uses
>   height modulo list length to return the receivers for height 9000.
>
> Receiver also looks ahead, after it is a random portion between 0.75
>   and roughly 0.95 of the way to the next step so that there is no mass
>   downloading when the block height switches from x999 to x000. To
>   resist ddos attacks and to work even when some web sites are down, it
>   picks the page which the majority of peers have available. The step
>   size of 4000 gives an update roughly each month.
>
> Disbursing the Share The generation share is 90% of the block, which
>   is 90% * 50,000 devcoins = 45,000 devcoins. It is disbursed to the
>   devcoin addresses in the receiver file, in round robin order. In each
>   generation round, for a given block height, the index of the line of
>   addresses is the block height above the start of the round, modulo the
>   number of addresses. The code snippet for that follows below.